# how to avoid read_sql_query data truncation for the returned set

Tags: python, pandas

I'm executing a sql command which returns a create table statement provided by my database, PostgreSQL.
In order to execute the sql command I use:

```
import io  
import json  
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import psycopg2 as pg
import boto3
from datetime import datetime 

conn = pg.connect(
    host=pgparams['url'],
    dbname=pgparams['db'],
    user=pgparams['usr'],
    password=pgparams['pwd'])  
createTable_sql = "postgresql select which returns the create table statement"   

df_create_table_script = pd.read_sql_query(createTable_sql ,con=connection)
```

My scope create a table. The table creation script is returned by PostgreSql after executing via Pandas / Python the "pd.read_sql_query" command.

If I execute the "createTable_sql" in an pgsql interpreter (e.g. pgadmin, etc.) it works fine and as a result I'm having only one column having the expected create table statement, or just a plain string having a length of 512 characters.

The content of "createTable_sql" variable is:

```
    createTable_sql= "SELECT cast ('CREATE TABLE dbo.table1 (" ...  
    createTable_sql= createTable_sql + "|| string_agg(pa.attname || ' ' || pg_catalog.format_type(pa.atttypid, pa.atttypmod)|| coalesce(' DEFAULT ' || (select pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) from pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d where d.adrelid = pa.attrelid and d.adnum = pa.attnum and pa.atthasdef), '') || ' ' || case pa.attnotnull when true then 'NOT NULL' else 'NULL' end, ',')"
    createTable_sql= createTable_sql + " as column_from_script from pg_catalog.pg_attribute pa join pg_catalog.pg_class pc on   pc.oid = pa.attrelid    and pc.relname = 'tabl1_source' join pg_catalog.pg_namespace pn on  pn.oid = pc.relnamespaceand pn.nspname = 'dbo' where pa.attnum > 0  and not pa.attisdropped group by    pn.nspname,     pc.relname,     pa.attrelid;"
```

The result when executing this sql command should be :

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.table1 (col1 datatype, col2, datatype, ....etc) -total number of charters from script is 512.
```

My issue is that the Pandas read_sql_query, or read_sql has a limitation (or at least is what i think) for the returned data set.
I was expecting the returned or read data set to have 512 characters, but the read_sql method is truncating it.

The result i'm having when i try to access the result returned by Postgresql (db engine) is:

```
' CREATE TABLE dbo.tabl1 (col1...'
```

Therefore instead of the full text (representing the table creation script) I'm only having something which is truncated after the first couple of characters.

Initially I assumed it was only truncated when i was using the print() function to get the returned result, but the value itself is truncated as well.

I even tried another approach, such as:

```
conn = pg.connect(
                host=pgparams['url'],
                dbname=pgparams['db'],
                user=pgparams['usr'],
                password=pgparams['pwd'])
sql =createTable_sql 
copy_func_csv = "COPY ({sql_cmd}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(sql_cmd=sql, head="HEADER")  
cur = conn.cursor()
store = io.StringIO()
cur.copy_expert(copy_func_csv , store)
store.seek(0)
df_new = pd.read_csv(store, engine='python', true_values=[True, 't'],false_values =[False, 'f'])
table_script = df_new .column_from_script.to_string(header=False,index=False)
```

But the table_script content was still truncated, looking like:

' CREATE TABLE dbo.tabl1 (col1...'

Is there any way I can retrieve a response set, meaning a single column (e.g. Col1) which can have a datatype definition such as Varchar(1000), or STR?

Regards,

Comment: Can you (1) clarify if you are trying to create a table in Postgresql using pandas `read_sql_query`, and (2) post examples of the output you currently have, and examples of the output you are expecting?

Comment: @tnwei: i've updated my initial post. Hope, now it much more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running the same query from using `pgadmin` works fine, perhaps try running the query directly from `psycopg2`? Try the following code chunk in place of `pandas`:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(createTable_sql)
result = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: thanks:) I could kiss you. I've spent yesterday a tone of time trying to split the returned string into smaller chunks, just to get rid of the truncation and it was a nightmare . Many thanks again.